# Hive versions pattern

Tags: apache, hadoop, hive, cloudera, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm going through Hive release versions and observed the pattern of Hive versions seems bit wired.

After 1.2.1 release which is on 27 June 2015, next version is 2.0 on 15 Feb 2016 and the versions continues. Again on 7-Apr-2017 i.e recently again Hive released 1.2.2 versions. I didn't get why again 1.2.2 instead of 2.x.y.

Can someone shed some light.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the answer in the screen shot you have attached.
There are 2 product lines.
Hive 1.x works with both Hadoop 1.x.y and Hadoop 2.x.y
Hive 2.x works only with Hadoop 2.x.y

https://hive.apache.org/downloads.html